# php clean up a string to be saved as .csv

Tags: php, csv, web

My data is stored in a single string variables and all lines are broken using \n

```
"10, 20, jump\n 15, 16, walk\n, 30, 10, run\n"
```

How would I clean this up to saved as a .csv? because all functions that I find only take arrays and I receive the data as a string.

[Edit]

It's saved into a file but it has the wrong formatting when I open the file

```
$fileData = fopen('test.csv', "w");
fputs($fileData, fputcsv($stringData));
fclose($fileData);
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using to generate the csv.

Comment: Tried [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)? Example: `$string = str_replace('\n', "\n", $string);`. With single quotes, you'll get the literal `\n` and with double quotes, you'll get a line break.

Comment: Define "cleaning up".

Comment: Looks like it's mostly already in a CSV format (other than the comma after the second `\n`), you just need to either save that to a file, or convert it to a multidimensional array and then back out.

Comment: if you want an array to pass to your csv, you can do `explode('\n', $str)`, you'll get an array of strings, then (if you need) foreach this array and do `explode(', ', $str)` on each row to get columns

Answer (score 0):

using magnus example this worked well

```
$string = str_replace('\n', PHP_EOL, $stringData);
```

As before opening the file data had \n in it